# Iphone Lock Screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, locking, widget, screen

friends, I am new to Iphone development, I am creating a simple analog clock, infact I have already created one ( i am basically an Android Developer - created same as widget for android too), Iphone does not seem to support widgets, but I was wondering if it is possible to create a lock screen app or something (i.e. when screen locks iphone shows a clock) is it possible that my clock replace the iphone one, any ideas , thanks in advance

Comment: You'll find that Apple places very strict limits on what developers can do as a general rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is impossible to replace the lock screen of iOS devices with a custom one.  iOS apps are not allowed to "lock" the system by any means.  Can't avoid the user pressing the home button.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. There is no public API for the lock screen.

Answer (score 1):

Although you may be able to find a way to accomplish your goal in development, it will almost assuredly be rejected by Apple.  Here is an excerpt from the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

> 10.4 Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-app widget experiences will be rejected

Comment: Why did they allow the "Desktop" app to be published?  I use it all the time as a way to run two of their "applets" at the same time.

Comment: @gonzobrains Most likely because they did not create an alternate desktop environment as in Gnome vs KDE and the "widgets" do not operate within the home screen environment.  The desktop app looked very much like an app and not like a functional home screen or like widgets on the home screen of the device.

Answer (score 1):

It is 100% possible but not approved by Apple. You can develop an app but will never be part of the app store... You can however use it for personal use or share it through a Cydia repo (jailbroken devices). But it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with all of you, although i agree a long time ago.. I Just browsing the app store and found an application that can change the way user unlock the iphone after it lock.. Here's the app "Slide your phone"